# AJAX Control Toolkit issue: CollapsiblePanelExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, controls, toolkit, collapsiblepanelextender

I've been banging my head against the wall with the following issue:

My mock-up site works as intenden in Firefox:

[http://www.plasus.com/test/work/work/Default.aspx][1]

In all other browsers, the collapsible panels and all other AJAX ControlKit stuff is immediately visible to the user, which is not at all intended.

What could possible be the reason for this problem?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="collapsePanel" Height="0">
```

You could trying setting the Height="0" of the collapsedpanel as per the snippet from the Ajax control toolkit samples. This should work from css too using height:0px;

Answer (score 1):

I actually found the bug: If you do not explicitly set the height and width of the SliderHandle in CSS (provided that you load the handle graphics from an img-source), all browsers apart from Firefox will fail to render the Slider in a collapsed collabsiblePanelExtender.